# Facebook в C# Windows Forms: нужна функция Login

Tags: c#, winforms, facebook

Пишу программу автоматизатор под социальную сеть Facebook

Моя программа должна состоять из граф Email: и Password и кнопки Connect или SignIn для входа в Facebook как на сайте, но не через WebBrowser так как Браузер сам по себе жрёт очень много ресурсов, может быть это возможно сделать через BackgroundWorker или ещё как-то

Одним словом, мне нужен пример авторизации для настольного приложения Windows  в facebook для дальнейшей навигации по сайту facebook и сбора информации из исходного кода.

Answer (score 1):

Авторизация на фейсбуке осуществляется с помощью GET- или POST-запроса к серверному скрипту на сайте фейсбука.
В HTML-коде страницы есть так называемая форма - контейнер, который содержит адрес данного скрипта (аттрибут action) и поля Email и Password, которые содержат информацию, передаваемую скрипту при нажатии Sign in.
Можно передавать их данному скрипту и непосредственно с помощью HttpWebRequest, минуя их текстовые поля.

Почитайте здесь, что такое GET- и POST-запросы и что такое формы.
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php
http://blog.foolsoft.ru/php-post-i-get-zaprosy-dlya-nachinayushhix/
Про HttpWebRequest найдёте в интернетах сами.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ в любой форме, сочту написанное вами после ответа за так называемую Мотивацию, так как вы понятия не имеете кол-во моих успешных видов деятельности, сейчас я дошел к программированию за счет не доверия к людям, не могу довериться написать программу пишу её сам. Снова Благодарю за ответ надеюсь он поможет мне быстро разобраться с моим проектом.

Comment: К Сожалению вам не удалось мне помочь. Рассказать мне о принципе работы get post запросов( точнее не рассказать) а тем более не предоставить мне никакого наводящего примера на решение моего вопроса относительно facebook, мда... Громко только "P.S" пишете, но  все равно, хоть что-то написали, Вопрос ещё актуален. Прошу помощи у остальных программистов...

Comment: "Рассказать мне о принципе работы get post запросов"
А что изменится? Если Вы не можете прочитать то, что дано в готовом виде по ссылкам, то не поймёте и в пересказанном виде.
----
Сделайте скрипт для приёма запросов по одному из тех примеров. Отправьте запрос вручную - через адресную строку браузера.
Сделайте форму на HTML для этого скрипта и отправьте запрос из неё.
Отправьте запрос с помощью HttpWebRequest.
И поймёте, как это работает.
----
"а тем более не предоставить мне никакого наводящего примера"
На форумах я никому ничего не обязан. Платить другим людям Вы не хотите - работайте сами.

Comment: "Громко только "P.S" пишете"
Сижу часами и пишу всем гадости в P.S?
Нет - я смотрю на форму, в которой задан вопрос, и по ней знаю, где трудолюбивый человек, а где бездельник, кто уважает чужой труд, а кто уважает только себя.
И в зависимости от этого отвечаю.
И вот с Вами я снова попал в цель - всё, что думал о Вас по Вашему вопросу, лишь подтвердилось комментариями.